# R: What exactly are starting values in glm and how to specify?

Tags: r, glm

I tried to fit the following glm in R:

> ```
>         date_st period plot  rain    flow      api
> 1      5M29      1    A  16.0  0.7000   2.5000
> 2       6M4      1    A   9.5  0.2000  18.5000
> 3      6M12      1    A  18.5  0.8000  12.5000
> 4      6M16      1    A  10.0  0.2000  31.0000
> 5      6M21      1    A  24.0  1.0000  35.5000
> 6      6M22      1    A  65.5  3.2000  60.0000
> 7      6M24      1    A  18.5  0.6000 122.5000
> 8      6M27      1    A  23.0  1.0000 129.5000
> 9      6M29      1    A  13.0  0.5000 143.0000
> 10      7M9      1    A  52.0  2.3000  44.0000
> 11     7M13      1    A  37.0  1.4000  62.5000
> 12     7M26      1    A  39.5  2.8000   0.0001
> 13      8M1      1    A  72.5  4.0000  40.0000
> 14      8M2      1    A  20.0  1.1000 112.0000
> 15     8M23      1    A   8.5  0.4000   4.0000
> 16     8M24      1    A   8.5  0.3000  13.0000
> 17     8M29      1    A   9.5  0.1000  36.5000
> 18    10M17      1    A  41.0  1.1000  27.0000
> 19    10M26      1    A  13.0  0.4000  44.5000
> 20    10M28      1    A  19.5  0.4000  58.0000
> 21     3M21      2    A  31.0  0.6000   0.0001
> 22     3M26      2    A  27.0  0.4000  31.0000
> 23      4M6      2    A  40.0  0.7000  39.5000
> 24      4M8      2    A  20.0  0.4000  55.0000
> 25     4M11      2    A  26.0  0.5000  75.0000
> 26     4M17      2    A  63.5  1.3000  92.0000
> 27     4M26      2    A  15.5  0.2000  68.0000
> 28     5M13      2    A  14.5  0.2000  15.0000
> 29     5M24      2    A  15.0  0.2000  14.5000
> 30     6M21      2    A  31.5  0.7000   0.0001
> 31     6M30      2    A  75.0  1.4000  48.0000
> 32      7M4      2    A  91.5  1.6000  96.0000
> 33     7M10      2    A   9.0  0.1000 176.5000
> 34     7M12      2    A  66.5  1.2000 107.0000
> 35     7M17      2    A  19.5  0.2000  83.5000
> 36      8M7      2    A 102.0  3.6000  19.0000
> 37     8M10      2    A  36.0  0.8000 104.0000
> 38     8M11      2    A  29.5  0.6000 138.0000
> 39     8M18      2    A  44.5  0.5000 191.5000
> 40     9M11      2    A  27.5  0.3000  26.0000
> 41     9M16      2    A  29.0  0.3000  53.5000
> 42     10M2      2    A  29.5  0.4000  13.0000
> 43     10M6      2    A  35.0  0.4000  41.5000
> 44    10M13      2    A  23.0  0.4000  66.0000
> 45    10M15      2    A  57.0  0.7000  58.0000
> 46    10M21      2    A 133.5  2.3000 100.5000
> 47    10M28      2    A  68.0  0.9000 190.0000
> 48    12M24      2    A  26.5  0.7000   0.0001
> 49      3M1      2    A  21.5  0.3000   0.5000
> 50      3M5      2    A  33.5  1.1000  22.0000
> 51      3M8      2    A  64.0  1.2000  55.5000
> 52     3M19      2    A  58.5  0.8000  77.0000
> 53     4M14      2    A  50.0  0.8000  10.0000
> 54     4M17      2    A  48.0  0.6000  60.0000
> 55     4M24      2    A  95.0  1.7000  98.0000
> 56      5M2      2    A  25.5  0.3000  95.0000
> 57      5M6      2    A  78.5  1.0000  86.5000
> 58     5M13      2    A  79.0  1.1000 104.0000
> 59     5M31      2    A  37.5  0.5000  17.5000
> 60      6M8      2    A  29.5  0.3000  72.0000
> 61   4M9M18      3    A  54.0  0.9000  45.0000
> 62   9M9M18      3    A  52.5  0.9000  97.0000
> 63   9M9M18      3    A  23.0  0.2000 149.5000
> 64  14M9M18      3    A  47.5  0.5000 157.0000
> 65  20M9M18      3    A  31.0  0.2000 105.0000
> 66  26M9M18      3    A  44.5  0.2000  89.0000
> 67  29M9M18      3    A  27.5  0.1000 119.0000
> 68  30M9M18      3    A  46.5  0.4000 162.0000
> 69  6M11M18      3    A  23.0  0.3000  32.0000
> 70  28M2M18      3    A  23.0  0.2000  40.0000
> 71  10M3M18      3    A  39.5  0.4000  47.0000
> 72  10M4M18      3    A  23.5  0.2000  26.0000
> 73  14M4M18      3    A  25.0  0.2000  29.5000
> 74  29M4M18      3    A  29.0  0.3000  16.5000
> 75  20M5M19      3    A  72.0  1.2000   9.0000
> 76  28M5M19      3    A  35.5  0.1000  75.0000
> 77   7M6M19      3    A  49.0  0.6000  36.5000
> 78  27M6M19      3    A  35.0  0.2000   6.0000
> 79  29M6M19      3    A  64.5  0.5000  40.5000
> 80   3M7M19      3    A  29.0  0.1000 113.0000
> 81  11M7M19      3    A  32.5  0.1000 108.0000
> 82  14M7M19      3    A  21.5  0.1000  84.0000
> 83  18M7M19      3    A  38.5  0.1000  88.0000
> 84  22M7M19      3    A  31.0  0.1000 128.5000
> 85  26M7M19      3    A  59.5  0.2000 111.0000
> 86     5M29      1    B  16.0  0.4000   2.5000
> 87      6M4      1    B   9.5  0.1000  18.5000
> 88     6M12      1    B  18.5  0.5000  12.5000
> 89     6M16      1    B  10.0  0.1000  31.0000
> 90     6M21      1    B  24.0  0.6000  35.5000
> 91     6M22      1    B  65.5  2.1000  60.0000
> 92     6M24      1    B  18.5  0.3000 122.5000
> 93     6M27      1    B  23.0  0.5000 129.5000
> 94     6M29      1    B  13.0  0.2000 143.0000
> 95      7M9      1    B  52.0  1.5000  44.0000
> 96     7M13      1    B  37.0  0.7000  62.5000
> 97     7M26      1    B  39.5  1.7000   0.0001
> 98      8M1      1    B  72.5  2.4000  40.0000
> 99      8M2      1    B  20.0  0.5000 112.0000
> 100    8M23      1    B   8.5  0.2000   4.0000
> 101    8M24      1    B   8.5  0.1000  13.0000
> 102    8M29      1    B   9.5  0.1000  36.5000
> 103   10M17      1    B  41.0  0.2000  27.0000
> 104   10M26      1    B  13.0  0.1000  44.5000
> 105   10M28      1    B  19.5  0.1000  58.0000
> 106    3M21      2    B  31.0  6.0000   0.0001
> 107    3M26      2    B  27.0  1.5000  31.0000
> 108     4M6      2    B  40.0  2.8000  39.5000
> 109     4M8      2    B  20.0  0.6000  55.0000
> 110    4M11      2    B  26.0  0.4000  75.0000
> 111    4M17      2    B  63.5  1.1000  92.0000
> 112    4M26      2    B  15.5  0.9000  68.0000
> 113    5M13      2    B  14.5  0.2000  15.0000
> 114    5M24      2    B  15.0  0.3000  14.5000
> 115    6M21      2    B  31.5  4.7000   0.0001
> 116    6M30      2    B  75.0  1.4000  48.0000
> 117     7M4      2    B  91.5  1.9000  96.0000
> 118    7M10      2    B   9.0  0.2000 176.5000
> 119    7M12      2    B  66.5  2.1000 107.0000
> 120    7M17      2    B  19.5  0.3000  83.5000
> 121     8M7      2    B 102.0 14.8000  19.0000
> 122    8M10      2    B  36.0  2.0000 104.0000
> 123    8M11      2    B  29.5  1.3000 138.0000
> 124    8M18      2    B  44.5  0.7000 191.5000
> 125    9M11      2    B  27.5  1.9000  26.0000
> 126    9M16      2    B  29.0  1.5000  53.5000
> 127    10M2      2    B  29.5  3.7000  13.0000
> 128    10M6      2    B  35.0  2.9000  41.5000
> 129   10M13      2    B  23.0  1.5000  66.0000
> 130   10M15      2    B  57.0  2.8000  58.0000
> 131   10M21      2    B 133.5  3.4000 100.5000
> 132   10M28      2    B  68.0  1.1000 190.0000
> 133   12M24      2    B  26.5  4.4000   0.0001
> 134     3M1      2    B  21.5  1.4000   0.5000
> 135     3M5      2    B  33.5  0.4000  22.0000
> 136     3M8      2    B  64.0  1.1000  55.5000
> 137    3M19      2    B  58.5  0.8000  77.0000
> 138    4M14      2    B  50.0  2.8000  10.0000
> 139    4M17      2    B  48.0  1.9000  60.0000
> 140    4M24      2    B  95.0  3.9000  98.0000
> 141     5M2      2    B  25.5  0.5000  95.0000
> 142     5M6      2    B  78.5  1.0000  86.5000
> 143    5M13      2    B  79.0  0.8000 104.0000
> 144    5M31      2    B  37.5  0.1000  17.5000
> 145     6M8      2    B  29.5  0.0001  72.0000
> 146  4M9M18      3    B  54.0 11.2000  45.0000
> 147  9M9M18      3    B  52.5  3.1000  97.0000
> 148  9M9M18      3    B  23.0  3.7000 149.5000
> 149 14M9M18      3    B  47.5  3.5000 157.0000
> 150 20M9M18      3    B  31.0  6.0000 105.0000
> 151 26M9M18      3    B  44.5  3.1000  89.0000
> 152 29M9M18      3    B  27.5  1.5000 119.0000
> 153 30M9M18      3    B  46.5  3.0000 162.0000
> 154 6M11M18      3    B  23.0  5.7000  32.0000
> 155 28M2M18      3    B  23.0  3.4000  40.0000
> 156 10M3M18      3    B  39.5  3.0000  47.0000
> 157 10M4M18      3    B  23.5  2.6000  26.0000
> 158 14M4M18      3    B  25.0  1.6000  29.5000
> 159 29M4M18      3    B  29.0  1.5000  16.5000
> 160 20M5M19      3    B  72.0 10.9000   9.0000
> 161 28M5M19      3    B  35.5  1.3000  75.0000
> 162  7M6M19      3    B  49.0  6.0000  36.5000
> 163 27M6M19      3    B  35.0  4.2000   6.0000
> 164 29M6M19      3    B  64.5  2.3000  40.5000
> 165  3M7M19      3    B  29.0  0.1000 113.0000
> 166 11M7M19      3    B  32.5  0.6000 108.0000
> 167 14M7M19      3    B  21.5  0.2000  84.0000
> 168 18M7M19      3    B  38.5  0.4000  88.0000
> 169 22M7M19      3    B  31.0  0.4000 128.5000
> 170 26M7M19      3    B  59.5  1.5000 111.0000
> ```

```
library(glm2)
r.all.2 <- glm2(flow~period+(rain*api) - 1,  family=Gamma(link='identity'),  data=d)
summary(r.all.2)
```

but got this warning:

```
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
In addition: Warning message:
In log(ifelse(y == 0, 1, y/mu)) : NaNs produced
```

1. I know this have been asked several times and answered, but what exactly are starting values? In a fitted line, what does it correspond to?
2. How to specify starting values? For my case, only `start=c(1,1,1,1)` worked but not `start=c(b0,b1)`, `start=c(0,0)`, and `start=NULL`
3. Why did I get this warning? I do not have any 0 or NA values in my data.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the model you are trying to fit? Do you want an interaction between rain and api? Or are you literally trying to multiple them? If the latter, use `flow~period+I(rain*api)` instead. If the former, it's a bit odd to have an interaction between two continuous values.

Comment: It is the former. Interaction between rain and api.